# Page Arguments and Dynamic Pages

Tags: 7

I am trying to make dynamic pages using hook menu which is going fine but the problem is I want to add page arguments for the states. For example if someone goes to the url and there isnt a state in the url like california for example(site/listings/california) it would show a page not found error, and if found it would list the listings I have looped out in my function.

Any Suggestions?

```
/*
** Hook Menu
*/

function listings_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['site/listings/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'City Listings',
        'page callback' => 'business_listings',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'page arguments' => array('states', 'city_names'),
    );

    return $items;
}


/*
** State Listings
*/

function listing_states($state){
    $state = array( 
        'alabama' => t('Alabama'),
        'alaska' => t('Alaska'),
        'arizona' => t('Arizona'),
    //ect.....

    );
    return $state;
}

/*
** Company Listings
*/

function business_listings(){

    $states = listing_states(arg(2));

    $dbquery = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT CityName FROM {zipcodes} WHERE StateName = '".ucfirst(arg(2))."' ORDER BY CityName ASC");

    $cityname = '';
    $cityname .= '<div class="city-wrapper">';
    foreach ($dbquery as $dbrow) {
        $cityname .='<div class="cityname" style="float:left; width:200px;">';
        $cityname .= '<a href="'.arg(2).'/'.strtolower(urlencode($dbrow->CityName)).'">'.$dbrow->CityName.'</a>';
        $cityname .= '</div>';
    }
    $cityname .= '</div>';

    return array('states' => $states, 'city_names' => $cityname);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your menu callback to pass the third argument (state) to the page callback:

```
$items['site/listings/%'] = array(
  'title' => 'City Listings',
  'page callback' => 'business_listings',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'page arguments' => array(2),
);
```

Then update your page callback to use the new argument, validate it against the items returned by `listing_states()` (which doesn't look like it needs to accept an argument), and throw a 404 if validation fails:

```
/**
 * State Listings
 */
function listing_states() {
  $states = array( 
    'alabama' => t('Alabama'),
    'alaska' => t('Alaska'),
    'arizona' => t('Arizona'),
    // ...
  );

  return $states;
}

/**
 * Company Listings
 */
function business_listings($state) {
  $all_states = listing_states();

  if (!isset($all_states[$state])) {
    drupal_not_found();
  }

  // your other code here
}
```

Additionally, you should really read up on [Drupal's coding best practices](https://drupal.org/developing/best-practices), as there are numerous issues with your code. Other than formatting, your query is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack, your markup should be in a template file or a theme function, your CSS should be in an external CSS file, and your link should be using the `l()` function (or at least `url()` for the `href` attribute).

Comment: Thanks, yeah I know this is pretty sloppy, this is just a rough draft of the code, you know how it is when time is against you lol.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to change your listings_menu()

```
function listings_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['site/listings/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'City Listings',
        'page callback' => 'business_listings',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'page arguments' => array(3),
    );

    return $items;
}
```

Then you need to change your listings to accept that argument

```
function business_listings($states){
  $states = listing_states($states);

  $dbquery = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT CityName FROM {zipcodes} WHERE StateName = '".ucfirst(arg(2))."' ORDER BY CityName ASC");

  $cityname = '';
  $cityname .= '<div class="city-wrapper">';
  foreach ($dbquery as $dbrow) {
      $cityname .='<div class="cityname" style="float:left; width:200px;">';
      $cityname .= '<a href="'.arg(2).'/'.strtolower(urlencode($dbrow->CityName)).'">'.$dbrow->CityName.'</a>';
      $cityname .= '</div>';
  }
  $cityname .= '</div>';

  return array('states' => $states, 'city_names' => $cityname);
}
```